# Display Data that has no same ID from two tables in Select -> Option Value Format

Tags: php

The two tables below is an example of my table and their values.

```html
    Tables

    Table -> [post]                Table ->   [category]
      categoryID                    categoryID  |  name
        1                                1         Home
        3                                2         About
                                         3         Blog
                                         4         Email
                                         5         Contact
```

What I want to do is: To echo the `name` from Table `category` that has no same `categoryID` in Table `post` in `Select & Option Values` format.

Desired output:

```html
Displays in a `Select & Option Value Format`:

2 - About
4 - Email
5 - Contact
```

My code below displays all the `name` from Table `category`.

```html
<select name="categoryID" >
   <?php $catlist_sql="SELECT * FROM category";
    $catlist_qry=mysqli_query($con, $catlist_sql);
    $catlist_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($catlist_qry);
    do { ?>
     
  <option value="<?php echo $catlist_rs['categoryID']; ?>">
  <?php echo $catlist_rs['name']; ?></option>
     
<?php } while ($catlist_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($catlist_qry));
  ?></select>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the query is selecting all categories, it will display all categories. You can execute a query to only select the categories without matching id in post table. Something like this:

```
SELECT * from category
WHERE category.categoryID not in (select categoryID from post)
```

You can try  query in phpmyadmin first to make sure you use the correct syntax.

Comment: You have my up vote. I forgot the PHP function `not in`. Now it's working. Thank you so much!